# PyQt 3D for QtQuick (QML) support

Tags: qt, qml, pyqt5, qt3d

I'm developing a PyQt UI application with QML, and I need to use some 3D graphics, 
I saw that Qt has extensive 3D support for QML (example: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/examples/qt3d/simple-qml?h=5.14)

But when I checked in PyQt docs I found 3D support only for widgets and not for QML (here: https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/PyQt5/Qt3DExtras.html#PyQt5-Qt3DExtras)

**Am I missing something? Is 3D for QML not supported in PyQt?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe either PyQt or pyside are going to have classes that directly correspond to the same types in QML. Normally you would use the QML types directly in a QML engine (that might just happen to be hosted in a PyQt/pyside instantiated app).

Answer (score 0):

Official answer from Riverbank:

> It's currently a Qt Technology Preview. These are never supported by
>   PyQt until they become "official".
>
> Phil

I am resolved to using PyQt Widgets for the 3D graphics alongside the main QML application, this is not elegant but with some UI manipulations looks pretty transparent to user.